# ¿Cómo implementar correctamente caché de fragmentos en W3TC plugin?

Tags: php, wordpress, cache

He comprado la versión pro de W3TC sólo para poder implementar el caché de fragmentos pero no lo consigo. Hasta ahora: en el archivo wp-config.php `define( 'W3TC_DYNAMIC_SECURITY', 'somesecurestring' );`
En las opciones desde el panel de administrador he puesto el caché de página en Disk:Basic y he activado la late initialization desde la configuración de Caché de Página. Lo que quiero es que la barra de navegación no se cachee. Esto es lo que hago:

```
<nav id="navigation" role="navigation" class="clearfix">
                    <div class="shadow"></div>
                    <?php if (class_exists('UserProfile')) : ?>
                        <?php $up = UserProfile::getInstance(); ?>
                        <ul id="user-menu" class="menu">
                            <?php if ($up->current_user->ID == 0) : ?>
                                <li><a href="<?php echo get_permalink($up->signup_page) ?>">Registro</a></li>
                                <li><a href="<?php echo get_permalink($up->profile_page) ?>">Inicio de sesión</a></li>
                            <?php else : ?>
                                <li><a href="<?php echo get_permalink($up->profile_page) ?>">Hola, <?= $up->current_user_data->first_name ?></a></li>
                            <?php endif; ?>
                                <li class="logo_autobild"><a href="http://www.autobild.es/" target="_blank"><img src="<?php echo esc_url( home_url( '/' ) ); ?>wp-content/themes/cocheando/img/autobild.png"></a></li>
                        </ul>
                    <?php endif; ?>
                </nav>
```

todo esto iría encerrado entre etiquetas mfunc, pero... ¿cómo? Estoy muy perdido. Gracias!